# Searching For Text Including Double Quotes In SQL Server

Tags: sql

Can anybody tell me how I can query for an item having a double-quote (") in them? The query I am trying to run is

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Code = 'CAT"A"'
```

This query doesn't return anything although I do have an entry for CAT"A" 
I can find it using

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Code LIKE 'CAT%'
```

But the "Code" being used will be variable, so I cannot use LIKE in this case.
Any help is greatly appreciated :)

G

Comment: This one works for me `SELECT 1 WHERE 'CAT"A"' =  'CAT"A"'`

Comment: You problem is not reproducible check here it works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/350cf/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I realised the reason why it wasn't working was because I was using an Alias (Code was an alias).

Comment: Then you would have got a error saying column doesnot exist

Comment: It did allow the query to run. Basically, was something like 'SELECT ISNULL(xxx, '') AS Code ... WHERE Code = 'CAT"A"' instead of ...WHERE ISNULL(xxx, '') = 'CAT"A"'